# How to delete every line in word that starts with a certain word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an 150 page document in word and want to delete every word line that starts with the word "Answer: ....." after answer each line says something different, so I wouldn't be able to do a find all for answer to delete it

it would take hours to go through the entire document and find all the instances, can anyone share a vba that would do it for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard characters in **Find and Replace**. Expand the dialog by clicking on **More >>**:

[image: Find and Replace dialog]

---

If you really want to do this programmatically:

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = ... 'determine the document you want to act on, and fill it here

Dim p As Paragraph
For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
    If InStr(p.Range.Text, "Answer") = 1 Then p.Range.Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so here's what worked for me in ms word.
to be safe save a copy of the file first.
here are the steps.....

HOME
REPLACE
Find what:  enter the word that starts the lines you want deleted

for your example, enter Answer*

select the boxes
Use wildcards
Ignore white space characters

now hit Replace All and the selected lines will all go away.
Don't save the file if this doesn't work for you...........

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).